# Error when compile umfpack after the update of Mac

Tags: fortran, gfortran, umfpack

I was able to use umfpack, but I just found that I cannot use it as before. I guess the reason is my recent update of Mac.

I already installed SuiteSparse VERSION 4.5.4. I use the Fortran interface, umfpack.f90, from [http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/~lh/Fortran/UMFPACK/](http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/%7Elh/Fortran/UMFPACK/). And use `gfortran umfpack.f90 umfpack_simple_3subr.f90 -L/usr/local/lib -lumfpack` to compile. But I got the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__gfortran_os_error_at", referenced from:
      ___mumfpack_MOD_umfpack_zi_operator_pcsr in ccAIP7gL.o
      ___mumfpack_MOD_umfpack_zi_operator_pcsc in ccAIP7gL.o
      ___mumfpack_MOD_umfpack_zi_operator_csr in ccAIP7gL.o
      ___mumfpack_MOD_umfpack_zi_operator_csc in ccAIP7gL.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no clue about solving the problem. Any suggestion is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your subject line, you suggest that you updated the Mac. Do you mean a new MacOS version? I don't know much about it, sorry, but I think at some point recently, MacOS dropped support for 32bit binaries. Maybe that's the issue?
I suggest you let us know to which version of MacOS you updated, and even better, from which.

Comment: What exactly did you update? How did you install your gfortran? Did you reinstall it? Did you recompile UMFPACK with the reinstalled gfortran? We have several similar questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I use a new MacOS version, and the gfortran is reinstalled, as well. It is good to know that there are similar questions. Sorry that I cannot find them. Could you please share them with me? @Vladimir F Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Did you recompile UMFPACK with the reinstalled gfortran?" Please answer that, it is important. The other Q/A will be about the "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" error and libgfortran in particular, but not about UMFPACK specifically.

Comment: Hi @Vladimir F, thank you for pointing this out. I was not 100 percent sure about this because I never specify the version of gfortran when compiling code. But I just ran `gfortran --version` in the terminal, and it shows `GNU Fortran (GCC) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` It is new. Then I think yes, I did recompile UMFPACK with the reinstalled gforran.

Comment: So, what happened when you recompiled it? Or did you do it before asking? See also https://github.com/auto-07p/auto-07p/issues/9 "recompile everything".

Comment: Hi @VladimirF, sorry for the late reply. I kind of change the subroutine to avoid the problem. I will look into the thread you shared with me. Thanks a lot!